# Ember has-block to detect empty block

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-octane

In ember octane, is there a way to detect `{{yield}}` is not an empty string?

The `has-block` function will return `true` if we use an empty component like this
`<IntakeFormElement></IntakeFormElement>` while `false` when `<IntakeFormElement/>`.

How do I get both `<IntakeFormElement></IntakeFormElement>` and `<IntakeFormElement/>` return false?

```
{{#if (has-block)}}
    Content: {{yield}}
{{else}}
    No block
{{/if}}
```

Ember Twiddle code:

https://ember-twiddle.com/7bf99058ec9f125b8b88dd73350ad3b4?openFiles=templates.components.intake-form%5C.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.intake-form%5C.hbs

Comment: you cannot do this -- empty block is still a block

Comment: Can we wrap it in another function or a different function then?

Comment: nope -- instead, what I'd do is make a template-lint plugin that _specifically_ looks for invocations of this component, and throws an error if it contains an empty block. That way, you even get in-editor hints about what could be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since empty block is still a block, there is a way to convey to developers that they shouldn't use your particular component with an empty block.
Via [template-lint](https://github.com/ember-template-lint/ember-template-lint) plugin!

[Here is an example astexplorer.net](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/779e5ceacb9feed88061a334eb116d86/d9555ea38b07163ce3ec2cb999ee0f86a4d9c04c) that demonstrates the logic that you'd use.

```js
    ElementNode(node) {
      if (node.tag === 'MyComponent') {
        if (node.children.length === 0) {
          console.log(`use ember-template-lint's log function to log a lint error`);
        }
      }
    }
```

Here are the docs for creating a template-lint plugin: https://github.com/ember-template-lint/ember-template-lint/blob/master/docs/plugins.md

And some example template-lint plugins:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-template-lint-plugin-prettier
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-template-lint-plugin-css-modules
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-template-lint-plugin-tailwindcss